# Pandas merge two tables on one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes df1 and df2 with CODE_STD in common. I want to merge into a dataframe that has 58 rows like df1 and include ASSET_ID and ASSET_ID2.

df1 has length = 58

| ASSET_ID | CODE_STD |
| --- | --- |
| 1424242 | 28 |
| 1424300 | 2086 |

and df2 has length = 11

| ASSET_ID2 | CODE_STD |
| --- | --- |
| 1424230 | 28 |
| 1424231 | 87 |

This is what I tried and it always return a dataframe with length 100. How can I join the two tables

```
t = pd.merge(df1,df2, on=['CODE_STD'], how='outer')


df1.to_dict()
{'ASSET_ID': {0: 1424242,
  1: 1424243,
  2: 1424244,
  3: 1424245,
  4: 1424246,
  5: 1424247,
  6: 1424248,
  7: 1424249,
  8: 1424250,
  9: 1424251,
  10: 1424252,
  11: 1424253,
  12: 1424254,
  13: 1424255,
  14: 1424256,
  15: 1424257,
  16: 1424258,
  17: 1424259,
  18: 1424260,
  19: 1424261,
  20: 1424262,
  21: 1424263,
  22: 1424264,
  23: 1424265,
  24: 1424266,
  25: 1424267,
  26: 1424268,
  27: 1424269,
  28: 1424270,
  29: 1424271,
  30: 1424272,
  31: 1424273,
  32: 1424274,
  33: 1424275,
  34: 1424276,
  35: 1424277,
  36: 1424278,
  37: 1424279,
  38: 1424280,
  39: 1424281,
  40: 1424282,
  41: 1424283,
  42: 1424284,
  43: 1424285,
  44: 1424286,
  45: 1424287,
  46: 1424288,
  47: 1424289,
  48: 1424290,
  49: 1424291,
  50: 1424292,
  51: 1424293,
  52: 1424294,
  53: 1424295,
  54: 1424296,
  55: 1424297,
  56: 1424298,
  57: 1424299,
  58: 1424300},
 'CODE_STD': {0: 28,
  1: 28,
  2: 28,
  3: 28,
  4: 28,
  5: 28,
  6: 80,
  7: 80,
  8: 80,
  9: 80,
  10: 87,
  11: 87,
  12: 87,
  13: 87,
  14: 87,
  15: 87,
  16: 87,
  17: 87,
  18: 87,
  19: 87,
  20: 106,
  21: 106,
  22: 106,
  23: 106,
  24: 106,
  25: 106,
  26: 106,
  27: 106,
  28: 106,
  29: 106,
  30: 106,
  31: 119,
  32: 119,
  33: 119,
  34: 119,
  35: 119,
  36: 119,
  37: 119,
  38: 119,
  39: 119,
  40: 192,
  41: 2005,
  42: 2005,
  43: 2005,
  44: 2005,
  45: 2005,
  46: 2005,
  47: 2086,
  48: 2086,
  49: 2086,
  50: 2086,
  51: 2086,
  52: 2086,
  53: 2086,
  54: 2086,
  55: 2086,
  56: 2086,
  57: 2086,
  58: 2086}}

df2.toDict()
{'ASSET_ID2': {0: 1424230,
  1: 1424231,
  2: 1424232,
  3: 1424233,
  4: 1424234,
  5: 1424235,
  6: 1424236,
  7: 1424237,
  8: 1424238,
  9: 1424239,
  10: 1424240,
  11: 1424241},
 'CODE_STD': {0: 28,
  1: 80,
  2: 87,
  3: 87,
  4: 106,
  5: 106,
  6: 106,
  7: 119,
  8: 119,
  9: 192,
  10: 2005,
  11: 2086}}
```

Comment: try using how='left' instead of outer

Comment: I tried outer,inner,left,right and it returns the same table of length 100

Comment: @MinhHuynh would you be able to run `df1.to_dict()` and `df2.to_dict()` and paste the results into your question? Thanks!

Comment: What's the desired output for the example data you've given? And do you have multiple ASSET_IDs with the same CODE_STD in either table?

Comment: @MinhHuynh if you are sure that no other unwanted columns are present in the second df, then try a drop_duplicates after the left merge and see what happens

Comment: added to_dict()

Comment: Yes, there are multiple ASSET_IDS with the same CODE_STD on table1 only. CODE_STD values are the same on both tables and unique for table 2.

Comment: @BluegirlFK Drop_duplicates don't work for me

Comment: @oh_my_lawdy the desired output is : table of 58 rows like df1, with three colums: ASSET_ID, ASSET_ID2, CODE_STD

Comment: You're right, multiple values have the same ASSET_IDS in table 2 (for example, 2 values with number 28) so table 1 will have to duplicate those with asset values. Hence 100. I chose another and unique values in the extended table 2 and it solves the problem. Thank you for the answers. All answers  are correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a left join here but you won't get 58 rows as you expect:

`final_df = df1.merge(df2, on='CODE_STD', how='left')`

The final dataframe has 100 rows, due to your data:
for one `CODE_STD`, you often have more than one `ASSET_ID_2` in df2.

Example: for `CODE_STD` == 106, there are these `ASSET_ID_2` values in df2: 1424234, 1424235, 1424236.

Thus, for every line in df1 with `CODE_STD` == 106, the final dataframe will have 3 lines and not 1. As 106 exists 11 times in df1, you'll have 11*3 == 33 lines for this `CODE_STD`.

If this is not what you want (if you want to keep only one line from df2), then you'll have to think of a rule to choose one of the 3 lines.

I hope it's clear!